# Create an app from a bash script that accepts arguments?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

As it says ... in OSX can i create an application based off a bash script - that accepts arguments ?

So for example i can run in terminal :

```
open /path/to/MyBashScriptApp.app myArgument1
```

This app will run with the argument passed to it?

I know i can rename to .command - but i need it to be an app .

Comment: Why do you *need* it to be an app file?

Comment: I've created an OSX app in Titanium... as far as i can figure out the Titanium api can only launch OSX apps & not scripts etc. I need to take the arg (its a file path) from Titanium, push it into another app that can launch the file using the associated application. I'm sure there must be a better way but i haven't a clue what it could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Automator, which can be found in your

```
/Applications/Utilities/Automator.app
```

With it you can easily package a `bash` script into an app, accepting file names.  Look for an action called "Run Shell Script".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OS X 10.6 then you can do:

```
% open /path/to/App.app --args arg1 arg2 ...
```

Check out this related question from [superuser](http://superuser.com)

https://superuser.com/questions/180995/passing-command-line-args-to-open-on-mac

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an .app yet - this is what i'm trying to build.  Is there a way to shove this into an .app container?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a command line interface to Automator, automator(1), which has an -i & -D switch for user-specified input.